# How to Find/replace with Regular Expressions and Wildcards in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need some help identifying a find/replace regular expression I could use to find a string of data that has two dates between pipes and replace the first date with a new date in Notepad++. I've done some research, but don't follow how this could be done. Last resort, I'll manually replace them all, but that isn't ideal.

Each row on the file has other information before and after the date section specified below; however, I expect that could be ignored since we're only wanting to use find/replace for the dates.

Here's 3 lines that may exist on the file.

```
|05/28/2016|12/31/2050|
|04/13/2014|12/31/2050|
|12/17/2013|12/31/2050|
```

I'm looking for an expression that would allow me to find/replace the first date within the first set of pipes with an alternative date I specify.

Find this...

```
|Wildcard Section|12/31/2050|
```

Replace with this...

```
|6/1/2016/12/31/2050|
```

Can this be done?

Thanks,

Brandon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as 6/1/2016 doesnt change or is not a variable you can do something like this

On Find what: field add `(.*)(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})(\|\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}.*)`

On Replace with: field add `($1)6/1/2016($3)`

On the top regex we break the match to 3 part (they are stored in $1, $2 and $3 respectively) for each section we need. We need to replace the middle date, $2 above replace statement will do the job.

find/replace window configuration screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/bjcnf8

Comment: Thanks! I'll test it out. Would it change any if I needed to add a zero in the replacement date? ie. I noted 6/1/2016, but it should really be present on the file as 06/01/2016.

Comment: Success! This worked beautifully (once I made sure I had it right in the window). I updated the replace string to add the other zeroes as needed without issue.

Comment: One last thought to make sure I follow how this was setup... The beginning part ".*" starts the wildcard section, the "\d means 0-9 integer and {2} means two of them, the \| means pipe in the literal sense and then the close of the wild is .* once again, is that correct?

Comment: Everything you said is correct except  "\| means pipe". \| is to escape the | since | means "or" literal in regex. Our intension is to keep the middle | on the final output so we need to escape it. Actually you don't need to escape it, just replace \| with a dot ".", it should still work.

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense. Saved me hours of time. Thanks!